# Мониторинг работы скрипта python

Tags: python, windows

Время от времени необходимо поднимать питон скрипт посредством другого питон-скрипта. В моей голове выстраивается логика, что с помощью модуля schedule раз в минуту проводится проверка включен ли другой скрипт, если нет - скрипт-менеджер поднимает его. Из-за неопытности не особенно представляю, как это можно реализовать на практике.

Также было бы круто после запуска основного скрипта скриптом-менеджером видеть основной скрипт в панели задач.

Основной скрипт работает на Windows Server 2019 и должен работать 24/7

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если держать скрипт в subprocess, то можно через join дождаться его завершения.

Comment: А почему не хотите написать сервис?

Comment: Т.е. сервис? Не до конца понимаю

Comment: Службу виндовс, которая будет работать без взаимодействия с пользователем

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но боюсь, что все имеющиеся способы это сделать мне не подходят, либо я в силу разных причин не могу их корректно реализовать. Когда скрипт падает, сервис не перезагружается, я не знаю как решать этот вопрос.

Comment: Сделай так чтоб супервайзер не падал - минимум кода = минимум ошибок.

Comment: "другой скрипт" что делает? в нем нужен интерактив?

Comment: Распишу иерархию: есть основной скрипт, бот телеграм. Иногда происходит переключение VPNа, из за чего бот падает. Мне нужен супервайзер, который бы отлавливал падения и поднимал скрипт обратно.

Comment: Если он падает, от смены сети, то он сам себя поднять может) не пишу ботов с впном - надо посмотреть код

Comment: Там ошибки выдает не сам скрипт, а библиотека telebot.

Comment: @Gradusov с телеботом не работал, но ошибки можно отлавливать через `try except` и выполнять какие-либо действия при ошибках, вряд ли так уж необходимо усложнять с запуском в другом скрипте.